# prevent add-on being enabled in lower Blender version than 2.8

Tags: scripting, add-on, versions

is there a canonical solution to this?

I'm one of the developers of Sverchok and we are more frequently getting installation issues where people install the 2.79 version of Sverchok on Blender 2.8+. We maintain two different Sverchok codebases for Blender 2.79 and 2.8+, and they are massively, *massively*, different.

Is there anything simple we can stick in the `__init__.py` that will prevent the user from enabling the 2.79 version of the add-on in blender version `2.8.0` or above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Blender 2.80 already protects against enabling incompatible add-ons. If the Blender version in the `bl_info` is too low, it will display a warning in the preferences. Blender will not run the `register()` function on these add-ons. However it does allow to tick the checkbox and the user may get the impression that it's properly enabled.

[image: Warning in preferences]

If you want to avoid that, you can check the Blender version and raise an exception in your `__init__.py`. This will prevent the checkbox from being enabled and the user gets an error message right away. I'm not sure if it will have the intended effect, since some users may not read or understand the error message.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Version Check Add-on",
    "author": "Robert Guetzkow",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 79, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Sidebar > My own addon",
    "description": "Checks if the correct version of Blender is used",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "3D View"}

import bpy


if bpy.app.version > (2, 79, 0):
    raise Exception("This add-on is incompatible with Blender versions newer than 2.79.\n"
                    "For Blender 2.8 please download the version from the following link:\n"
                    "[insert link here]")


class EXAMPLE_PT_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "My own addon"
    bl_category = "Name of your tab"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label("Congratulations, your Blender version is supported.")


classes = (EXAMPLE_PT_panel,)


def register():    
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: yep. lovely stuff - thank you.

Comment: @zeffii you're welcome. Although I'm not (yet) familiar with the add-on activation code in Blender, it may be an easy patch to disable the checkbox when the add-on is recognized to be incompatible.

Comment: we do a lot of stuff in `__init__.py` before `register` , raising an Exception is fine with me.

Comment: @zeffii ok. It would still make sense to discuss this with the devs though. I can't think of any reason why it should be possible to enable the checkbox when the add-on is incompatible, other than the code change would be unnecessarily complicated for this small change.

Comment: @zeffii You could also open the URL to the correct add-on version on Github using the `webbrowser` module. This may be not well received though, since it's very invasive behavior for an add-on.

Comment: This helped me, because in the 3.x versions of Blender above 3.0, the bl_info "blender" minimum version doesn't do anything. I wanted 3.4 for the minimum version and used this method.